# Alternative to Linear Actuators or Linear Actuators with small load limit and 70cm movement

Tags: home-automation, actuator, automation

Are there any Alternative to Linear Actuators which are not as expensive ?

OR Linear Actuators with small load limit (about 20Kg) and 70cm movement ?

Thanks and sorry if this was posted in electrical engineering, because I did not find the mechanical engineering community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only need positioning accuracy to ~0.1 mm, you can use standard threaded rod driving a carriage with a single matching nut. My local hardware store has 3-foot sections of 8-32 threaded rod for less than $10. Any sort of small DC motor with a gearhead will do to drive it. Making an encoder for the rotation of the rod is harder, but you only need to sense rotation to 45 degrees to get 0.1 mm resolution.

Comment: You can get Acme thread rods and anti-backlash nuts cheaply on eBay. If you want better accuracy, use a ballscrew. Can be driven with a stepper or DC servomotor.

Comment: Actually I was just seeing a similar project with a stepper motor and a threaded rod moving an object. Is 1200g/cm stepper motor enough or a lot to move a 20KG object on a rail with wheels ?

Comment: I'd expect no problems, particularly if you pay attention to your wheels. 8-32 gives a lot of mechanical advantage when converting from rotary to linear motion. Even if you go to an Acme or something similar (which typically have a much coarser pitch, you still shouldn't have a problem. What you'll need to watch out for is trying for too much acceleration and losing lock on a stepper.

Comment: Another thing to consider if you go the really cheap route - slew speed. Let's say you use a 200 step/revolution stepper with a max step rate of 1000 steps/sec (a reasonable ballpark number). Then the fastest you can spin the shaft is 5 rps. With a 32-pitch thread, the fastest your carriage will move is 5/32 of an inch per second. That's not real fast.